# How do you add a jFrame to your main class in Netbeans?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

So I have made a Jframe with a lot of elements and buttons and things in it, but I am new to using NetBeans.  Upon creating the java application a main class.java was created and upon adding the jframe another jframe.java was created.  How do I get the main class to open, read, and run my jframe.java?  I can upload the specific code if need be.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Consider taking a read through [How to create a GUI with Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)

Comment: Yet another case of 'the tail wagging the dog'.  Learn how to code a GUI by hand before getting into using GUI builders like as offered by Netbeans.  They are great productivity tools, but useless until you understand how to make a GUI using plain old Java code.

Answer (score 5):

To call a certain method from another class, you must first create a new object for that class, like this:

```
Jframe frame = new Jframe();
frame.setVisible(true); //or whatever the method is in jframe.class
```

Maybe rename the actual class name from *jframe* to something like *frameone*. I've heard that naming classes the same as classes in the Java API will cause trouble.

Or, you could put it all in one class, with either two separate methods or put it all in the main method. **If this doesn't help, then please paste the exact code on pastebin.org and give a link.**

Comment: *"**If this doesn't help, then please paste the exact code on pastebin.org and give a link.**"*  I vote 'no' to that.  1) External links go stale. 2) Many people cannot or will not follow links.  3) It encourages people to come back with things like *"Here are the **links** to the **4 source files** used."* -- Better to post a [MCTaRE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Tested and Readable Example) as an [edit to the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/21591807/edit).

Answer (score 1):

Look at this sample example and learn how to set frame visible

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class exp{  
    public static void main(String args[]){ 
        JFrame jf=new JFrame("This is JFrame");
        JPanel h=new JPanel();
        h.setSize(100,100);

        h.add(new JButton("Button"));
        h.add(new JLabel("this is JLabel"));
        h.setBackground(Color.RED);

        jf.add(h);
        jf.pack();
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jf.setVisible(true);

    }  
}
```

---

**Useful Links**

1. [Designing a Swing GUI in NetBeans IDE](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/quickstart-gui.html)
2. [Creating a GUI With Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) (As @MadProgrammer Commented)
3. [Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/learn/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to this, but I got a form up. Woo hoo!

```
1) The project created my main function in japp1.java
2) I created a JFrame, file jfMain.java
3) While there was probably a way to reference it as it was, I didn't see how right away, so I moved it to a peer level with the japp1 file, both in a folder called japp1 which will cause them to get built together, having the same parent reference available.

src\
    japp1\
        japp1.java
        jfMain.java

4) Then instead of creating a generic JFrame with a title, I created an instance of my class... 
5) I gave it a size... 
7) Then showed it...

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    JFrame frame = new japp1.jfMain();
    frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(700, 500));
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

I had already put some code in my jframe... to show a messagedialog with JOptionPane from a mouseclick event on a button and set some text for some textfields.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Moving it looks to have broke further GUI builder editing of it, so later Ill figure out how to reference it w/o moving it.

Comment: Btw, the location was good, I just created my form class file in the wrong place originally.  After recreating the form, at the right location, it worked the same and I didn't need my step 3 of moving it anywhere manually.  It is important to learn what the IDE is doing with all of its generated code and how to play nicely with the IDE to not mess things up. :)  I'm thinking, lot's of backups (of probably the whole project for that matter) is a good idea, while you're learning.

Comment: One last thing for now, this was kinda nice.  I centered the form, but I have 2 monitors, so I came up with this before calling setVisible (since my frame was being shown at 0,0 logically on whatever screen I was on)...

        Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        int x = dim.width/2-frame.getSize().width/2;
        int y = dim.height/2-frame.getSize().height/2;        
        frame.setLocation(frame.getLocation().x + x, frame.getLocation().y + y);

Comment: One other note, I changed the type for the new logic, to be...

    japp1.jfMain frame = new japp1.jfMain();

That allowed me to call a public rtn I made in the jframe class called mainLoad after showing the jframe

    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.mainLoad();